# RODBC Snowflake Query Backend Text in R Console

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rodbc

I've used RODBC to connect to a Snowflake instance, run queries, and then manipulate the data in R before without issue. I moved to a different computer and now I'm having an issue with RODBC, at least I think that's where the problem lies.

I still have connectivity and can run queries, but now the R console returns a bunch of backend(?) processing text that slows the process down considerably. Small example, but a RODBC::sqlQuery() will pump out line-after-line of red text in the R console that looks like:

2021-04-14T14:40:20.467 TRACE 737 Simba::Snowflake::SFQueryResult::BulkFetch: row count: 100, old row count: 100
2021-04-14T14:40:20.468 TRACE 737 Simba::Snowflake::SFQueryResult::MoveToNextRow: row index: 99701
2021-04-14T14:40:20.468 TRACE 737 Simba::Snowflake::SFQueryResult::BulkFetch: row count: 100, old row count: 100
2021-04-14T14:40:20.468 TRACE 737 Simba::Snowflake::SFQueryResult::MoveToNextRow: row index: 99801

How does one turn off this back-end processing text -- for lack of a better term -- off?

Comment: You probably have the [logLevel](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#configuration-parameters) set to 6 (Trace) in ODBC configuration.

Comment: @Sergiu that was exactly the issue. Thank You!

Comment: I face the same issue @JNP978 . How can I change this parameter to 5?